# Vue 3, provide() can only be used inside setup()

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-composition-api

I have an `AppReplyToMessage` component that is supposed to send data to the `AppSendMessage` component to notify it that the message being sent is a reply. I'm doing it as follows; The `AppReplyToMessage` component:

```
<script setup>
import { provide } from "vue";
import AppSendMessage from "../AppSendMessage.vue";

let props = defineProps({
    message: {
        type: Object,
        required: true,
    },
});

let message = toRefs(props).message;

const replyToMessage = () => {
    const message = {
        reply: true,
    };

    provide("reply", message);
};
</script>
<template>
  <button@click="replyToMessage">
    Reply
   </button> 
</template>
```

and in the `AppSendMessage` component I'm receiving the data as follows:

```
<script setup>
  const reply = inject("reply", null);
</script>
```

The code though is not working an I'm getting the error `[Vue warn]: provide() can only be used inside setup().` in the console.

Comment: Are you using vite or Vue cli?

Comment: I am using Vite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disregarding the small errors you have in your source code, like forgotten `import { inject } from "vue"` in the `AppSendMessage` component, you have two important design problems.

1. The Vue `props` are readonly. **Do not try to mutate the `props` in components!**
2. The Vue warning states that you should run `provide()` only from `setup()` or from `<setup script>`.

You call `setup()` from a lambda function.

```
const replyToMessage = () => {
    const message = {
        reply: true,
    };

    provide("reply", message);
};
```

You should run `provide("reply", message)` directly from `<setup script>`

3. And then, you declare a new `message` constant in the lambda function, which has no relation to your `message` prop.

Please read the Vue Docs about Components and [Provide / Inject](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html#provide-inject) thoroughly and check the [SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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) with `Provide / Inject` example.

Here is the [SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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) with the solution

```
const reply = ref({});
provide("reply", reply);

const replyToMessage = () => {
    reply.value.message = props.message;
    reply.value.reply = true;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

`provide` should be used at the top level of setup, not within another function within setup.

First create an empty ref, and pass that to the provide function. Then within your `replyToMessage` function, set the value of the ref when the button is clicked.

```
<script setup>
import { provide, ref } from "vue";

// ...

const reply = ref(null);
provide("reply", reply);

const replyToMessage = () => {
    const message = {
        reply: true,
    };

    reply.value = message;
};
</script>
<template>
  <button @click="replyToMessage">
    Reply
   </button> 
</template>
```

[Docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html#working-with-reactivity)